# JPG PDF Files in Storm

Tags: distributed, distributed-computing, apache-storm, distributed-system

I wanted to know if it's possible to manipulate JPG files in Storm? Should we expect any issues if JPG or PDF files are being transmitted from bolt to bolt? We are manipulating these files in very large volume, and need a distributed platform to keep up.

From my understanding, messages (and hopefully files) go into in memory queues between bolts.

Has anyone tried to pass JPG or PDF files between bolts in Storm? Are there any limitations that would prevent this from working? If not Storm, can anyone recommmend an appropriate platform?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this, but I did some experiments with large tuples which worked fine. I would not expect any problems. As long as you can provide appropriate (de)serialization (best via Kryo), Storm does not care what data it is. To Storm, everything locks like a bunch of bytes anyway (except for key attributes that are used for `fieldsGrouping`).

You might also check out [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/) **(Disclaimer: I am a contributer)**